# C# play Spotify Uri

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a music player using the Spotify api.
The main functionality is therefore to play music.
Thanks to the API I get the spotify URI of the music I want to play but I don't know how to play this music from the URI.
Thanks

Comment: What specific part are you struggling with? Provide some more details, and maybe add the code you've already tried. Does the Spotify API come with any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a supported Feature of Spotify.

A few things to consider:

1. [The API Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/)
2. [The Web Player SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/#tutorial-and-examples)

You could try to use the Web API to get a token, and the data you need such as the URL.
Once you have this, you could embed a browser in your app to act as the player. Perhaps with something like [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) even. The WinForm, WPF, or whatever UI you provide could then use the API to/ Web Player to send the correct on the fly commands to control / play the music.